# Need help alphabetising quiz results in a .CSV

Tags: csv, python-3.x, formatting

I have to create a quiz that asks user's name and which class they're in, after this I need to format the results in their respective .csv files. I have created the quiz and the results write into three seperate .csv files (one for each class) however I don't know how to format the results alphabetically.

```
import random #random functions
import os #provides a way of using operating system dependent functions
import csv

print ("Welcome! What is your name?") #asks name and starts quiz
name = input().title() #capitalises the name for future printing
Class = str(input ("What class are you in? "))
while Class != "1" and Class != "2" and Class != "3":
    Class=str(input ("What class are you in? "))

print ("Welcome to the quiz" ,name,"!")
score = 0 #sets score to 0
Q = 0 #sets question number to 0
while Q < 10: #only asks questions up to ten of them being asked
    operator = random.randint (1,3) 
number1 = random.randint (1,10) 
number2 = random.randint (1,10) 
if operator == 1: #addition q's
    print ("What is", number1, "+", number2,"?" )
    ans = number1 + number2

elif operator == 2: #subtraction q's
    print ("What is", number1, "-", number2,"?" )
    ans = number1 - number2

else: #does the only other option, multplication q's
    print ("What is", number1, "*", number2,"?" )
    ans = number1 * number2

while True: 
     try:
       InputAns = int(input())  #the answer the user input
     except ValueError: #Stops anything but integers being used
         print ("Please enter a number")
         continue
     else:
        break #stops a loop

if InputAns == ans: #input answer equals true answer
            print ("Thats correct!")
            score += 1 #adds a plus one to their score

else: #When the input answer doesnt equal the true answer
             print ("Sorry, thats incorrect")



Q += 1    #Keeps asking question until it gets to 10, this part adds one to the Q number each time.

if score<5 and score>0:
print ("Sorry", name, "you only got",score, "out of 10")

elif score==0:
print ("Commiserations",name,

       "you got",score, "out of 10!")

else:
    print ("Congratulations", name, "you got", score, "out of 10")  #shows user their score


if Class == "1":
    with open('Class 1 Results.csv', 'a') as f:
        file_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
        file_writer.writerow((name, score))    #stores any user in Class 1's      results in their respective table

elif Class == "2":    
    with open('Class 2 Results.csv', 'a') as f:
        file_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
        file_writer.writerow((name, score))    #stores any user in Class 2's results in their respective table

 elif Class == "3":    
    with open('Class 3 Results.csv', 'a') as f:
        file_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
        file_writer.writerow((name, score))    #stores any user in Class 3's results in their respective table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the data after writing to the file. For sorting, the data will be read, then sorted using `Operator` module and then re-write the sorted data.

```
import random #random functions
import os #provides a way of using operating system dependent functions
import csv
import operator

def sortcsv(csvfilename, columnNumberforSort):
    data = csv.reader(open(csvfilename),delimiter=',')
    sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(columnNumberforSort))
    with open(csvfilename, "w") as f:
        fileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
        for row in sortedlist:
            fileWriter.writerow(row)

print ("Welcome! What is your name?") #asks name and starts quiz
name = input().title() #capitalises the name for future printing
Class = str(input ("What class are you in? "))
while Class != "1" and Class != "2" and Class != "3":
    Class=str(input ("What class are you in? "))

print ("Welcome to the quiz" ,name,"!")

score = random.randint(1,100)

if Class == "1":
    with open('Class 1 Results.csv', 'a') as f:
        file_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
        file_writer.writerow((name, score))    #stores any user in Class 1's      results in their respective table
    sortcsv('Class 1 Results.csv', 0)

elif Class == "2":    
    with open('Class 2 Results.csv', 'a') as f:
        file_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
        file_writer.writerow((name, score))    #stores any user in Class 2's results in their respective table
    sortcsv('Class 2 Results.csv', 0)

elif Class == "3":
    with open('Class 3 Results.csv', 'a') as f:
        file_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
        file_writer.writerow((name, score))    #stores any user in Class 3's results in their respective table
    sortcsv('Class 3 Results.csv', 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I go about organising by average score and highest to lowest?

Comment: Done the lowest to highest, however Average is causing trouble for me, I also need to record the last three scores for each student, is there any way to delete any after that?